# Rotating an object to match a vector

Tags: c++, vector, rotation, direct3d

I thought that I was doing this correctly for the longest time, but however I believe I may be doing this in a very wrong way.

I have a 3D engine with world terrain, and objects can be placed on the ground, when they get placed they get oriented to the terrain they are on (rotated).  The way I did this was like so:

```
D3DXVECTOR3 tNormal = GetNormalFromFile( ... );  //Get the terrain's normal

placeItemData.placeMesh.meshRot.z = (acos(tNormal.x) - (D3DX_PI/2));
placeItemData.placeMesh.meshRot.x = -(acos(tNormal.z) - (D3DX_PI/2));
```

I store the rotation as a vector in radians: x,y,z rotation, where Y is up.  So I calculate the rotation of the X and Z axis and rotate accordingly.  The player can manually rotate the object around the Y axis before placing it, and all of this has worked fine, supposedly.

As I continued to improve my item placement code, I realized this was not working for near-vertical planes. For example, trying to place a picture on a wall.  This code seems to work to place items on near horizontal (flat) terrain, but the rotations are way off for a vertical wall.

Am I missing a simple calculation here?  Do I need to calculate in the y-axis value somehow?  I attempted to to calculate the rotation using atan2 functions as well:

```
placeItemData.placeMesh.meshRot.z = (atan2(finalNormal.x,finalNormal.y) );
placeItemData.placeMesh.meshRot.x = (atan2(finalNormal.z,finalNormal.y) );
```

But I ran into similar problems.

Do I need to be using quaternions for these calculations?  Am I able to store the final rotation values in a 3D vector (x,y,z) easily again?

I appreciate any help!

**Update 1**

Here is an image using this code:

```
meshRot.z = - atan2(sqrt(finalNormal.y^2 + finalNormal.z^2), finalNormal.x);
meshRot.x = - atan2(finalNormal.y, finalNormal.z);
```

[image: prob1]
<sub>(source: [crystaldragon.com](http://www.crystaldragon.com/TempImages/prob1.png))</sub>

As you hover the mouse over the stone, the normal of the triangle is computed (for the picture, the normal of the stone face is (0.637, -0.014, 0.770) ).  Of course the wood block you see in the stone, should be directly laying on top of the stone side (like being hung as a picture).

**Update 2**

From testing an "wall" positioned in the z-axis in my world, I seem to have the code working for just all cases where y=0.  I am able to place the object on all the vertical walls, but not the horizontal(top) of the wall.

Here is the current code:

```
placeItemData.placeMesh.meshRot.x =  -(atan2(finalNormal.y, sqrt((finalNormal.x * finalNormal.x ) + (finalNormal.z * finalNormal.z)) ) + (D3DX_PI/2));
placeItemData.placeMesh.meshRot.z =  -(atan2(finalNormal.z, finalNormal.x ) + (D3DX_PI/2));
```

As long as the y-normal is a value of 0, the object will attach to each of the vertical walls, however not the horizontal (since the y-normal is a non negative number obviously).  Hopefully the final step is to figure out the final calculations I need to enter in as a y-value into the equation, but I am still coming up with failed attempts.

Comment: I know rotations, but I don't know Direct3D. Two values for the rotation are enough, but when you use the values in `meshrot` to rotate the object, do you do it with your own code or do you invoke a Direct3D function?

Comment: I just know that this is going to be related to the discontinuity of `atan2` at `atan2(0, -x)`.

Comment: This is how I do my rotation matrix:
`D3DXMatrixRotationYawPitchRoll(&matRotate, 0.0f, meshRot.x, meshRot.z );

D3DXMatrixRotationYawPitchRoll(&matRotate2, meshRot.y, 0.0f, 0.0f );

D3DXMatrixMultiply(&matRotate, &matRotate2, &matRotate);`

Comment: That picture really isn't clear. Which face of the stone are we talking about? Where are the axes? Is that black blob the wooden block? what orientation should it have?

Comment: Sorry for the poor image.  What I was trying to illustrate was that that algorithms were not lining up to the rock face, the vector I gave (0.637, -0.014, 0.770) is the normal of the side of the rock face of which the object (the wood piece sticking out) is supposed to be aligned to.  Obviously the rotations are not lining up to that normal vector correctly.

Comment: I am supposedly getting closer to the answer.  I was doing some research and found your algorithms in some code on the web and I am starting to understand the algortihm, for now I use this:
`VGlobal::mainPlayer.placeItemData.placeMesh.meshRot.x =  -(atan2(finalNormal.y, sqrt((finalNormal.x * finalNormal.x ) + (finalNormal.z * finalNormal.z)) ) + (D3DX_PI/2));`

`VGlobal::mainPlayer.placeItemData.placeMesh.meshRot.z =  -(atan2(finalNormal.y, finalNormal.x ) + (D3DX_PI/2));`

This seems to work so far for any values of finalNormal.x and finalNormal.y (up), but no finalNormal.z values work.

Comment: Added "update 2" to the top, I am much closer.

Answer (score 0):

For a near horizontal (flat) terrain, the terrain is on the *X-Z* plane, so the *y* value for the normal is most likely 1.0, which should give you the correct rotations without using the y normal.

However, when adding an object to the wall, the *y* normal will be required to compute the *y* component of the rotation. You say the player can manually rotate the object around the *Y* axis before placing it.

Is that where you're computing the y component of the rotations using the *y* value of the normal? If not, ensure you're computing it too. Otherwise, you're computing rotations in 2D, and somehow extrapolating it to 3D.

Comment: So for the placement I am currently not using the y component in any calculations for the item placement.  The y-rotation is simply added in as its own "separate" rotation of the object after the fact.  I put the rotation code into the comment block above.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Quaternions. You can get it to work without them but your code would have to have a lot of checks for zeros and there would be discontinuities if you try to animate anything. There's a bit of a learning curve with quaternions but once you have:

- a rotation method
- a conversion from Cartesian (or polar or whatever) to quaternion
- a conversion from quaternion to Cartesian (or whatever)

It's really very simple to use and they are the right choice for 3d manipulations.

I'll be honest and say you don'thave to understand the math either to get it to work; you just have to be able to follow the rules of quaternion math.

Comment: Thanks.  I may go this route if I cannot get the more "conventional" method to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Direct3D, but going by a quick look at the docs, it looks as if this is what you want:

```
meshRot.z = - atan2(sqrt(finalNormal.y^2 + finalNormal.z^2), finalNormal.x);
meshRot.x = - atan2(finalNormal.y, finalNormal.z);
```

(I don't know if this is the correct syntax e.g. for `sqrt`, but you see what I'm trying to do.)

The rotation about Y ("yaw") can be left to the user-- it corresponds to rotating a statue from north-facing to east-facing, or hanging a painting on the wall upside-down.

I'm assuming that the rotations are about the object-fixed axes. If that's not the case then the solution will look quite different. Give it a try, and if it doesn't work we can try a couple of simple test cases to pin it down.

Comment: I greatly appreciate the help!  I have added an update to my original post showing the current result of the code with some explanation.  I will also keep doing some research as well.